# Dplyr's tbl_df gives unexpected behavior when selecting column by string

Tags: r, dplyr

Often, when using dplyr programmatically, I'll want to select a column by its name, where the column name is stored as a string in some variable.

I've noticed that attempts to do this with dplyr often lead to unexpected results. This seems to be as a result of how tbl_df is handled.

Below are some examples:

```
## regular data frame:
df = data.frame(subject = 1:3, resp = c(2,3,3))   # example dataframe
response_column = "resp"                     # I want to select the contents of a column with a string                       

# for loop over unique values:
unique_responses = unique(df[,response_column])
for (resp in unique_responses) {
  cat("\nA response:", resp)
}

# convert column type:
df[,response_column] = as.character(df[,response_column])
str(df) # modified the column
```

So these are the sorts of things I'm used to doing. Accessing column's contents, converting them and reassigning them, taking their unique values, etc.

But when the data.frame has class tbl_df and tbl, things don't work as well.

```
## with tbl_df and tbl 
require(dplyr)
df = data.frame(subject = 1:3, resp = c(2,3,3))
class(df) = c("tbl_df","tbl", class(df))
class(df)
df[,response_column] 

# for loop doesn't seem to know what to do with this:
unique_responses = unique(df[,response_column])
for (resp in unique_responses) {
  cat("\nA response:", resp)
}

# as.character seems to concatenate the entire column into one string!
df[,response_column] = as.character(df[,response_column])
df
```

I wasn't sure what to make of this behavior (i.e., intentional vs. bug), or generally, what the best practice is to be able to use the same (programmatic) code across normal data frames as well as dplyr's data frames.

Comment: `tbl_df` documentation says: `[` Never simplifies (drops), so always returns data.frame. Does it explain the problem?

Comment: Use `df[[response_column]]` instead of `df[ ,response_column ]` to extract the values of the column.