# Transforming column type from read_tsv in R?

Tags: r, dplyr, readr

I'd like to programmatically transform the type of a column in an R data frame read from a file.  Example below is broken.  Advice?

File foo.tsv:

```
x
1
2
```

Code that is broken:

```
foo = read_tsv("foo.tsv")
foo[,'x'] <- as.integer(foo[,'x'])
```

Error:

```
Error: (list) object cannot be coerced to type 'integer'
```

In this case `read_tsv` already returns an integer, but I want to write a function that passes in the column names.

This code works:

```
foo$x <- as.integer(foo$x)
```

I don't know how to modify that to let me give column names in a variable.

If I initialize foo as a data frame like this:

```
foo = data.frame(x=c("1", "2"))
```

then the original `foo[,x]` variant works, leading me to believe it's something about the type of thing returned by `read_tsv`.

That shows a bunch of stuff:

```
> str(foo)
Classes ‘tbl_df’, ‘tbl’ and 'data.frame':   2 obs. of  1 variable:
 $ x: int  1 2
 - attr(*, "spec")=List of 2
  ..$ cols   :List of 1
  .. ..$ x: list()
  .. .. ..- attr(*, "class")= chr  "collector_integer" "collector"
  ..$ default: list()
  .. ..- attr(*, "class")= chr  "collector_guess" "collector"
  ..- attr(*, "class")= chr "col_spec"
```

I'm using R 3.3.2, and dplyr 0.5.0.

Comment: This is how the package authors want it to be. There was a similar (maybe duplicate) question last week or so. The consensus there is that the tbl_df object has to be referred to in specific ways (it is not a data.frame). [This post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28231334/dplyrs-tbl-df-gives-unexpected-behavior-when-selecting-column-by-string?rq=1) may also be a duplicate.

Comment: Relevant reading from the [`tibble NEWS`](https://blog.rstudio.org/2016/03/24/tibble-1-0-0/): "Tibbles also clearly delineate `[` and `[[`: `[` always returns another tibble, `[[` always returns a vector.".

Comment: Here is [the post from last week](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42860504/difference-in-logical-statement-between-and/42861111#42861111).

Comment: Thanks! If you submit "This is a feature not a bug. Convert the object to a data frame" as an answer, I will accept it.

Comment: Or as I tried to describe in my comment, use `[[`; `foo[['x']] <- as.integer(foo[['x']])`. Also described in the comments of the first post @imo pointed to.

Comment: Thanks @Henrik I ended up using that.